# How to connect with an node js server with android client using sockets

Tags: android, node.js, server, socket.io, client

I want to develop a chat application using sockets in android with the help of node js server. Could you please tell me how the socket works? and how to connect with the node server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must search it in google, you can find many good tutorial about your question, this site is not a good place for this type question

Answer (score 1):

The following node.js code was working perfectly from server side, for both emit and listen the messages from client side

```
> var app = require('express')(); var http =
> require('http').Server(app); var io = require('socket.io')(http);
> app.get('/',function(req,res){
>     res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html'); }) io.on('connection',function(socket){
>     console.log('one user connected '+socket.id);
>     socket.on('message',function(data){
>         var sockets = io.sockets.sockets;
>         /*sockets.forEach(function(sock){
>             if(sock.id != socket.id)
>             {
>                 sock.emit('message',data);
>             }
>         })*/
>         socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
>     })
>     socket.on('disconnect',function(){
>         console.log('one user disconnected '+socket.id);
>     }) })
> 
> 
> 
> http.listen(3000,function(){
>     console.log('server listening on port 3000'); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these link to connect your chat app with NodeJS Server. [This](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat) is the demo app using Socket.io and [this](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) is the method by which you can connect your app with your NodeJS server. Hope this will help you.

Comment: already tried all those codes.But the android was not connecting to node server

Comment: See in your NodeJS server how the codes are written for connecting users.. May be the method written in your server sides are different.